# "repeat" structure in Java

Tags: java, loops

I'm teaching programming to beginners (starting at 12-15 years old) and one of the choices we made (because it was natural in Python) was to teach the notion of "repeating an action" before the notion of variables.

We warted in Python with

```
for loop in range(10):
```

without speaking about variables of arrays and in C++ with

```
#define repeat(nb) for(int _loop = 0 ; _loop < (nb) ; _loop++)
```

The idea was to hide the complexity of a classical loop in order to insist on the "repeat" part. We are not hiding from the students the fact that "repeat(10)" is not a part of C++, 
it's just a way to simplify the learning.

In Pascal we can't do much more than

```
for loop := 1 to 10 do
```

but that's ok because its's not that difficult to remember.

I was looking for something similar in Java and I found that :

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.AbstractList;

class Range {
    public static List<Integer> size(final int end) {
        return new AbstractList<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer get(int index) {
                return 0 + index;
            }
            @Override
            public int size() {
                return end;
            }
        };
    };
}

public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] argv) {
    for (int loop : Range.size(10)) {
        System.out.println("xx");
    }
    }
}
```

The

```
for (int loop : Range.size(10))
```

is still easier to remember than

```
for(int loop = 0 ; loop < 10 ; loop++)
```

but there is two problems :

- two variables are needed for imbricated for loops : I dont think we can do much about that
- we are having warnings because the variable `loop` is not used

Do you see a better solution that what we have ?

Once again, we only want to provide some "tool" at the beginning phase in order for the students to "repeat" actions, before knowing anything about "variables". We are not hiding from them that's is not in the langage and after a few exercises (~80-100) we are asking them to use the real syntax.

---

We have approximately 20 exercices before introducing variables : some about printing texts but mostly we are providing one library with objects you can manipulate (hence the variables are hidden in the object state). You can think of the "logo-turtle" for example. This way the notion of "loop" can be manipulated and "seen" before introducing explicit variables and you can have interresting exercises really fast.

One example, in Python, where you want to visit every case of a 10x10 table once and only once and then be back at your starting point (lower-left corner) :

```
from robot import *

top()
for loop in range(4):
   for loop in range(8):
      top()
   right()
   for loop in range(8):
      bottom()
   right()
for loop in range(8):
   top()
right()
for loop in range(9):
   bottom()
for loop in range(9):
   left()
```

This exercise is not that easy but the syntax is really simple and allow the student to concentrate on the "algorithmic" part and not the "langage" part.
After a few exercises the students are getting interrested and we can introduce more syntax and more difficult concepts like the variables.

Comment: It feels to me that the concept of a variable is a more fundamental one than the concept of looping. Any reason you don't want to introduce variables first?

Comment: I've edited my question to explain a bit more about our exercises.

Comment: Variables still feel fundamental enough to me that I would really suggest introducing those *before* loops. It sounds like you're basically trying to turn all other languages into Logo - but they're not.

Comment: IMHO Its best to teach people how to use a language the way its usually used.  A loop in Java if one of the most basic constructs.

Comment: I agree that it was easier for Python or C++. For Pascal and OCaml we didn't change anything. If I don't find a good way for Java we'll use the classical syntax. We are more interesting in the algorithmic process, the langage is just a tool that we can "adapt" for the first exercises.

Comment: If the language is just a tool, then why start with Java and not stick to Pascal for example, where you said you didn't had to change anything ?

Comment: We started in Python but the online plateform we are using allow Pascal, Python, OCaml, C, C++, Java and soon more of them. We are trying to have (as much as possible) the same exercises so that someone that want to learn Java can start, and be helped about the algorithms, by someone starting with an other language.

Answer (score 5):

Do you really need to use Java for those exercises? If other languages works for you then why not to use them? You can always move to Java when you students know basics like variables.

I agree that variables can be quite confusing from beginners - especially that their value can change all the time, it is not something people are used from algebra where values don't change once "assigned".

If you want to use Java, you could use while loop which seems to fit better. One dirty trick  how to avoid use of variable is following code - it use StackTraceElement instead of variable.

It prints

```
Hello A
Hello B
Hello C
Hello C
Hello C
Hello B
Hello C
Hello C
Hello C
Hello A
Hello B
Hello C
Hello C
Hello C
Hello B
Hello C
Hello C
Hello C
Hello A
Hello B
Hello C
Hello C
Hello C
Hello B
Hello C
Hello C
Hello C
```

Here is full source. main(Strinng[] args) method is code with loops, rest is supporting code.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Repeater {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(range(3)) {
            System.out.println("Hello A");
            while (range(2)) {
                System.out.println("Hello B");
                while (range(3)) {
                    System.out.println("Hello C");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean range(int size) {
        return Range.range(size);
    }


    public static class Range {

        static Map<StackTraceElement, RangePosition> ranges = new HashMap<StackTraceElement, RangePosition>();

        public static boolean range(int size) {
            final StackTraceElement stackTraceElement = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[3];
            //System.out.println(stackTraceElement);
            RangePosition position = ranges.get(stackTraceElement);
            if (position == null) {
                position = new RangePosition();
                position.size = size;
                ranges.put(stackTraceElement, position);
            }

            final boolean next = position.next();
            if (!next) {
                ranges.remove(stackTraceElement);
            }
            return next;
        }

     }

    public static class RangePosition {
        int current,size;
        boolean next() {
            current++;
            return current <= size;
        }
    }
}
```

But I'd prefer to use some language which supports this naturally.

Answer (score 3):

I would always introduce variables first. What are you going to do inside the loop without knowledge about variables ?

Apart from that maybe it would be easier to use a while loop. The head of a while loop is much easier and doesn't require variable definitions.
This is very simple to understand:

```
while (do_the_loop){
   //this is repeated
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java really is not suitable for this kind of task because it does not allow for functions to be passed.

The only way I can think of doing this without variables would be with an interface:

```
private static void repeat(int times, DoStuff what) {
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        what.doIt();
    }
}
private interface DoStuff {
    public void doIt();
}
```

And then use it this way:

```
repeat(5, new DoStuff() { public void doIt() {
            System.out.println("xx"); // whatever needs to be done
        }});
```

Which would be without variables but quite confusing at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really what you are searching for, but here is my opinion and how I would teach it. (Beware, I'm not a teacher at all :D)

Aren't there two different courses for this: Algorithms and Programming? In programming, you really should start off by teaching them the variables. It's not difficult at all. And I don't think that 20 exercises about algorithms are going to be that interesting for them. I think they will be more attracted to the power of computing something than either writing for loops inside each other. Writing a simple program that computes some summations and multiplications et cetera will do to introduce the idea of primitive variables. Then I would introduce the for loop. Demonstrate by printing 10 times some text in combination with the variable used in the for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    // Tell them that the 'i' is a variable as you explained before.
{
    System.out.println("This is line " + i);
}
```

Then writing an application that computes the factorial of a hardcoded number will be interesting, I think. This way, most of them will hopefully get the idea of working with variables. Then try to explain scopes.

```
int number = 5;
int factorial = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= number; ++i)
{
    factorial = factorial * i;
}
System.out.println(number + "! = " +  factorial);
```

Answer (score -1):

if you have a limit defined you have to use a while structure

while(myval < mylimit){

//do something

myval++;
}

but when the limit is unknow then you should use for or for each

for (int i =0; i< list.size();i++)
{

}
of by objects

for each (String myString : myStringArray){

}

Saludos